# How can I resolve Spring boot crud operation error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Field employeeService in `com.employee.controller.EmployeeController` required a bean of type `'com.employee.services.EmployeeService'` that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:

```
@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
```

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type `'com.employee.services.EmployeeService'` in your configuration.

I am just doing crud operation on employee by using spring boot and MySQL database but, I getting Error so, how to resolve this error.

Comment: Share with us your `EmployeeService` code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.